# Laravel Passport Unauthenticated after composer update

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

I've been working in this application for several years and while doing some updates my passport authentication broke. I update from passport 7.2 to 7.5 and it broke. I then updated to passport 8.5 and it still doesn't work.

I am getting the 401 `{error: "Unauthenticated."}` error.

I am using

- Laravel 7.28.1
- Passport 8.5.0
- Laravel Valet
- PHP 7.3

I am attempting to consume my own api and I've followed every solution I found on the internet, but no dice. I can access the routes using postman with an access token and if I move the route outside of the `auth:api` middleware, but I want to access the routes within the `auth:api`

Here is my current config.

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Passport::routes();
}
```

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            ... other middleware
            \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

In auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ]
]
```

bootstrap.js

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```

in a component.vue file

```
axios.get('/api/users?page=' + page).then((response) => {
    //
})
```

I've cleared configs and ran  `php artisan optimize:clear` and about a dozen of other things that I can't thing of right now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean 'it broke'? What happens, what errors do you get? did you check the console on the browser and the laravel logs?

Comment: Sorry, can't believe I left that out. I'm getting a 401 `{error: "Unauthenticated."}` error

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered exactly this problem with Laravel 7 and Passport starting around the time of this question posted (early September 2020). I couldn't pin-point the exact cause of the issue, but had to freeze my dependencies to avoid the problem. While debugging it seemed to me it wasn't a direct issue with Laravel or Passport, but rather a sub-dependency.

Just upgraded to Laravel 8 and Passport v10.0.1 and now everything is back to normal.